# Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\tan(x)\sin(\frac1{|x|+|y|})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

Calculate $\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\tan(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1{|x|+|y|}\right)$

We know that

$$-1\leq \sin\left(\dfrac{1}{|x|+|y|}\right)\leq 1$$

$$-\tan(x)\leq \tan(x)\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{|x|+|y|}\right)\leq \tan(x)$$

Taking the limit on both sides gives us $0$, therefore the limit is $0$.

Does this work? I am doubtful of the fact that $\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{|x|+|y|}\right)$ is undefined, so I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Just use $\left| \sin\left(\frac1{|x|+|y|}\right)\right|\le 1$ .  The sine function is defined for all $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$.

Comment: What would you say the limit is?

Comment: The limit is $0$.

Comment: $\sin (\frac{1}{|x|+|y|})$ is defined, except at the origin  where it is not. When we talk about $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ we do not care whether or not the function is defined *at* the origin. All we care about is what happens *near* the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT.-$$0\le\left|\tan(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1{|x|+|y|}\right)\right|\le |\tan(x)|$$

Comment: I did exactly this. its in the comments. Thanks for answer though

Comment: This is incorrect. The left hand side should be $-\tan(x)$

Comment: When using absolute values  this is unnecessary.